# spree: Missing required parameter :login

Tags: spree

I've just inherited a spree project that has an issue. On checkout, after the user provides their credit card information, the system has a rails exception. I'm looking for guidance on what might be requiring the login parameter.  I'm quickly learning how spree works, so any guidance is helpful. Thanks!

```
Started PUT "/checkout/update/payment" for 107.3.138.229 at 2012-09-28 08:52:11 -0700
Processing by Spree::CheckoutController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXX=", "order"=>{"payments_attributes"=>[{"payment_method_id"=>"2"}], "coupon_code"=>""}, "payment_source"=>{"2"=>{"number"=>"[FILTERED]", "month"=>"X", "year"=>"XXXX", "verification_value"=>"XXX", "first_name"=>"XXX", "last_name"=>"XXX"}}, "commit"=>"Save and Continue", "state"=>"payment"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 464ms

ArgumentError (Missing required parameter: login):
  active_utils (1.0.4) lib/active_utils/common/requires_parameters.rb:11:in `block in requires!'
  active_utils (1.0.4) lib/active_utils/common/requires_parameters.rb:4:in `each'
  active_utils (1.0.4) lib/active_utils/common/requires_parameters.rb:4:in `requires!'
  activemerchant (1.20.4) lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net.rb:74:in `initialize'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/gateway.rb:25:in `new'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/gateway.rb:25:in `provider'
  spree_core (1.1.3) lib/spree/core/delegate_belongs_to.rb:82:in `delegator_for'
  spree_core (1.1.3) lib/spree/core/delegate_belongs_to.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in delegate_belongs_to'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:128:in `block in gateway_action'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:172:in `protect_from_connection_error'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:125:in `gateway_action'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:22:in `authorize!'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/payment/processing.rb:11:in `process!'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:89:in `each'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:89:in `method_missing'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/order.rb:380:in `process_payments!'
  spree_core (1.1.3) app/models/spree/order.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Order>'
```

Comment: I just solved this. The payment method login is empty. (I'm convinced that I looked there before posting this. Sigh.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw your comment before answering, this UI element is too small! Anyway, good for common knowledge I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your authorize_net module is not provided required configuration. And/or configuration is not provided for your environment (gateways configurations are provided on a per-environment basis, so if you load production database configuration and run in development, you may not have required configurations).

And to get the big picture, authorize_net module is part of the [active_merchant](http://activemerchant.org/)  gem (checkout modules by Shopify) and extended for Spree in [spree_gateway](https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway/blob/master/app/models/spree/gateway/authorize_net.rb) and the configurations for active_merchant are managed by Spree and stored in database.

There is a configuration exemple provided in the [Spree guide](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/payments.html#specifying-configuration-options) :

```
# gateway/authorize_net.rb
class Gateway::AuthorizeNet < Gateway
    preference :login, :string
    preference :password, :string

    def provider_class
        ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway
    end
end
```

You can then set you login/password from the admin panel or seed them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue using autorize.net gateway as my payment methods.Before my seeting was without login and password due to which this rails exception come.Then i create test account on authorize.net and set this account login Id and key on admin side for authorize.net configuration and solved problem.

```
      Card Not Present Test Account

          API Login ID 3cm2NkD3GyyyW

          Transaction Key 6v7CEMcRq5H74p5yyg   #as password
```

even same error with paypal before giving test account credentials

Hope help others